# How to run a command when a libreswan tunnel connects?

Tags: ipsec

I would like to run a command (or wake up a process, or similar) when libreswan succeeds in connecting an IPSec tunnel (or connection, to use the configuration file's term).  My requirement is to run a command not when the connection is enabled but when it actually gets connected to a peer.

The leftupdown configuration setting allows one to specify a script which appears (from my experimentation) to run when the connection is enabled or disabled, but does nothing when the tunnel is actually established.

(I'm using CentOS 6.7)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I believe you're looking for the [_updown script](https://libreswan.org/man/_updown.8.html)